# What is an "active" statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

An interviewer just asked me that question, if I was familiar with "active" statements.

I then asked if she was referring to prepared statements, and she said no, I had no other choice but to answer "I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with them".

It seemed like it was not important at all, I still got a second interview.

However, after googling the question I haven't been able to find a reference to "active" statements.

I should have asked for the answer, but then again since it was an interview it would have not been an appropriate question.

Does anyone around here have a clue?

Thanks a bunch!

P.S. If this is not a good question for the community, feel free to close or delete the thread!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did they maybe mean "Active Record?" That's an object-relational mapping technique, used to match model-tier code to data code, and uses automatically generated SQL statements.